# Deterministic procedure to find irreducible polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, computational-complexity, computational-number-theory, computer-algebra

1. In $\Bbb F_q[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ given $d_1,\dots,d_n\in\Bbb N$ is there a deterministic $O(poly(nd\log q))$ algorithm to find an irreducible polynomial with $d=\max_{i\in\{1,\dots,n\}}d_i$ and $d_i=deg(x_i)$ at every $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ under $GRH$ (for $n=1$ case we have such an algorithm)?
2. Same as 1. but the irreducible polynomial differs from a $O(poly(nd\log q))$ list of irreducible polynomials each with $d_i=deg(x_i)$ at every $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ with or without $GRH$?

Is there such an algorithm for 2. under $GRH$ for at least $n=1$ case?

Factorizing $x^{q^{d}}-x$, the product of all irreducible polynomials whose degree divides $d$, collecting degree $d$ factors provides degree $d$ irreducibles in $\Bbb F_q[x]$. Is there an analog in $\Bbb F_q[x_1,\dots,x_n]$?